# pa11y/cypress using typescript

Tags: automation, cypress, pa11y

I have been asked to add pa11y to our existing cypress regression pack. I got a proof of concept project working installing and setting up the config and writing one tests, this worked out of the box as expected. However as I try to transpose the files into our existing project I am getting an error with invalid URLs. The difference is my POC was in the .js format but our main project is written in .ts. So the test file, config and command files are all .ts as opposed to .js. pa11y seems to be getting called....

[image]